# When running a ubuntu shell in Docker, a compiled binary shell script in path does not run, but a shell script on path does?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, ubuntu

Here is the GitHub repo for the question: https://github.com/NathanTPerkins/CoolProgram

The program is designed to test a Docker file that would compile at shell script using the "shc" package and then add the path to the folder containing the binary to the PATH variable.

The problem I am encountering is that there is no output with the binary file.

What happens:

1. when I use the "which" command, it gives me the correct path to the binary file
2. when I echo the PATH variable, the path to the directory containing the variable is in it
3. when I run the shell script like "test.sh", and nothing else, the output shows
4. when I got into the directory with the binary file and run it like "./test", there is output
5. when I run the binary like a command, "test", there is no output, no error, nothing it just moves to the next line on the shell

To sum up:

- root@1129847:/somedir# test -> nothing happens no output
- root@q0w9e8q:/somedir# test.sh -> shows the output of the shell script
- echo $PATH -> contains the path to the directory containing the binary file

Comment: have you tried with a different name for your file? test in ubuntu is normally an already deployed binary file `/usr/bin/test` https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html. If i just run test on my ubuntu system I also get no output returned. if possible try with a different name just ot be sure your not running into any conflicts of the shell or OS builtins

Comment: That works thank you so much. That sounds like something I should have checked or realized!

Comment: @ChrisDoyle+ `test` is a standard utility and there is (essentially always) an executable for it, but if that were the only problem `which test` would have found it. But `test` is a _frequently used_ standard utility and both bash and dash make it a **builtin**; see `type test` in either, or more informatively in bash only `type -a test`.